# C# Find and edit single object on list

Tags: c#, linq, list, class

```
public class kDrinki
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string nazwa { get; set; }
    public string skladniki { get; set; }
    public string opis { get; set; }
    public string sciezka { get; set; }

    public kDrinki(int _id, string _nazwa, string _skladniki, string _opis, string _sciezka)
    {
        id = _id;
        nazwa = _nazwa;
        skladniki = _skladniki;
        opis = _opis;
        sciezka = _sciezka;
    }
}
```

I have got that class. I created List lst_pDrinkow of object and added some form XML. I don't know how to find only single object (using object id not list id) from list and edit all his data(not only single parameter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var obj =  lst_pDrinkow.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.id==Id);
```

Where `Id` is the id of the object you are looking for.

If there is an object with the supplied `Id`, you will get it. Otherwise, the result would be `null`.

Once you get the object you want, it's very easy to update it's data.

```
if(obj!=null)
{
    obj.nazwa = "new value";
    // update the values of the other properties with the same way.
}
```

**Update**

While it is not your case, I have to note here that **if** there are *more than one* objects with the supplied `Id`, then you will get an exception. We usually use the `SingleOrDefault`, when we are sure that the object we are looking for it is unique if at all exists.

More formally:

> Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the
>   sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more
>   than one element in the sequence.

as it is stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Do I have to add this object to list at the end? Or changes are automaticaly saved ?

Comment: @GarryMoveOut no you haven't. Why so? Because variable called `obj` will hold a reference of the original object. So any change you will make to the properties of this object, will be reflected to the values of it's properties? Is that clear?

Comment: Oh I know understand that. I tested it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<kDrinki> items = new List<kDrinki>();
        var tmp1 = items.SingleOrDefault(a => a.id == 10);
        tmp1.skladniki = "new value";

        var tmp2 = items.SingleOrDefault(a => a.opis.Contains("some strings"));
        tmp2.skladniki = "new value2";
```